# Get detailed result from pt-query-digest

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, profiling, percona, pt-query-digest

I have slow query log file from [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) that using mysql as engine.

I am running [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/) with that log file. with following command.

```
pt-query-digest --report-all --limit=0% /tmp/mysql.slow_log.log > result.txt
```

this is output:
[image: Output]

How can i get more detailed output like in [here](http://www.ovaistariq.net/768/profiling-your-slow-queries-using-pt-query-digest-and-some-love-from-percona-server/#.VIgfiTGUeuF).
[image: What i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--log_slow_verbosity=full
```

**Caveat:**

This flag can only be used with the [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/slow_extended_55.html).